# What is the expanded spell list for warlocks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, spellcasting

I'm playing a warlock in 5e. I've been peeking through Google, but have found contradicting answers. What IS the Expanded Spell List? Is it a second spell list? Is it just spells I can get just like any other spell? What is it?

Comment: Do you have the Player's Handbook?

Comment: Yes I do. Reading over it right now

Comment: The [other question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64359/warlock-expanded-spell-list) is a subtly different question. Notably, the answers are different in what misconception is being clarified, which demonstrates that the real questions are different. I've reopened this.

Answer (score 12):

Each Patron has a list of spells.  In the description before the spell list, it says:

> The [patron] lets you choose from an expanded list of spells when you learn a warlock spell.  The following spells are added to the warlock spell list for you.

So the expanded spell list is not a list of auto-obtained spells (like cleric domain spells), but rather spells not normally on the warlock spell list that you are allowed to take as one of your normal warlock spells in addition to the standard list on pg 210 of the PHB.

For example: as a 3rd level Fiend Warlock, you know 4 spells, and you can choose from any of the combined choices of warlock spells on pg 210 of the PHB and the spells on the fiend expanded spells list (p. 109), but the Warlock will still only know 4 spells.

Answer (score 8):

The Expanded Spell List feature basically just says this:

> The
>   following
>   spells
>   are
>   added
>   to
>   the
>   warlock
>   spell
>   list
>   for
>   you.

So what does that mean? It means that wherever something references the Warlock spell list, it means all the spells normally on the Warlock spell list as well as all the spells on the Expanded Spell List.

Where this is usually going to matter is learning new spells. So, for example:

> At
>   1st
>   level,
>   you
>   know
>   two
>   1st‑level
>   spells
>   of
>   your
>   choice
>   from
>   the
>   warlock
>   spell
>   list.

So, when it says you know 2 1st-level spells of your choice from the warlock spell list, it actually means you know 2 1st-level spells of your choice, each of which can come from the list of spells in the back of the book under the Warlock heading, or the list under your Expanded Spell List feature.

Comment: Thanks for that. Another question I am having trouble with, is Expanding Spell slots. Does that mean the same thing?

Comment: @TheLeviathan I'm not aware of any feature called Expanding Spell slots - where did you read that?

Comment: I read it from the PHB. It said "The Warlock lable shows how many spell slols you have.
The lable also shows whallhe leveI of those slots is; all
of your spell slols are the same leveI. To cast one of your
warlock spells of 1st level or higher, you must expend a
spell slot. You regain all expended spell slols when you
finish a short l or long rest. 
For example, when you are 51h leveI, you have
lwo 3rd-level spell sioIs. To 1st-level spell
thunderwave, you must  spend one of those slots  and
you cast it as a 3rd-level spell."

Comment: @TheLeviathan Ah, right. If you have questions about how that works, you should probably ask in a separate question post - I could try to explain in a comment, but you'll get better answers if you ask it as its own question.

Comment: @TheLeviathan [Mostly covered here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46168/22566)

Comment: expend ≠ expand